# alert the ID of the Link the User Clicks On

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a couple links that each have unique IDs. I want to call a single function that when anyone of the links is clicked, the user gets an alert that says the link ID. I am stumped. Here's what I have. I want to do this with pure JavaScript.

My code:

```
<p><a href="#" id="link0">Link0</a></p>
<p><a href="#" id="link1">Link1</a></p>
<p><a href="#" id="link2">Link2</a></p>
<p><a href="#" id="link3">Link3</a></p>

<script>
function test(i) {
    alert("You just clicked on link:" + i); 
}

onclick = function () { 
    test(i);
};
</script>
```

Comment: The code you've got is a very very long way from being working javascript. `onclick` is not a function, and does not work anything close to the way you've written it. Some of the answers here will help, but I suggest finding some good tutorials to learn from, because although copying+pasting the answers below might get your code working, it won't help you understand how it actually works.

Comment: Do you want every link on the page to alert even if it doesn't have an id, or only links with ids, or  only links with ids that start with 'link', or only links that are inside of a certain kind of tag (like one with a class "alertlinks" or one that is a "p" tag?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName( "a" );

for ( var i = 0; i < links.length; i++ ) {
    links[i].addEventListener( "click", function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert( this.id );
    }, false );
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/t833R/)

Comment: That code will negatively affect other parts of the page. <a href="#home">Home</a>, for example, will alert nothing, and also will not get to it's destination.

Answer (score 1):

I just created an example for you using jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
       alert(this.id); 
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Yynw9/

To use jQuery you had to include the library in your header:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

Comment: no jQuery - read the requirements *I want to do this with pure JavaScript.*

Comment: jQuery is pure javascript ;)

Comment: the question didn't specify jquery, which usually means that the we shouldn't answer with a jquery solution. However in this case, the level of understanding demonstrated in the question indicates that jquery might be the most appropriate answer. But again, given what we can see in the question, I would suggest editing the answer to include a note about how to use jquery and how to add it to the site, rather than just providing jquery code, because if he tries to test that without knowing that, it won't work.

Comment: sure jQuery is JS, but it's 90K of additional weight to the page and 1 http request.. for this example it's just an overkill

Comment: added the hint for adding jquery.
Yeah but this example is surely only an excerpt of his code / project.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the javascript you are looking for:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i = 0, length = elements.length; i < length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener( "click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("You just clicked on link: " + this.id); 
    }, false );
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3R4FA/1/

The code loops first selects all your elements that are `<a>` tags. It then loops through this array, and adds a click event listener to each item. The use of the `this` keyword accesses the element that triggered the event, and then you can fetch the id.

Comment: I copy this from another post with the same exact answer: "That code will negatively affect other parts of the page. <a href="#home">Home</a>, for example, will alert nothing, and also will not get to it's destination."

Comment: Yes, that is obvious, but the poster asked to do this for each link. You can just remove the e.preventDefault() if you don't want to stop the default behaviour, or you can provide another identifier to attach to. As it is, there is no other identifier to attach the event to.

Comment: All of them have an id which starts with a 'key', the question has 'link' in all of the ids. And would you want to alert on a link that doesn't have any id at all?

Comment: I answered the question as it was stated, if the poster has more requirements, he can update the question, and then I can update my answer. Until then, debate is pointless! I can't answer your questions and neither can you, only the poster can.

Answer (score 0):

in browsers that support it, you can use querySelectorAll to grab all of the ids which begin with 'link' or you can add a class and use getElementsByClassName.. in legacy browsers, the solution is not as clean, but you can grab all of the 'a' tags in the document or inside of an element, and check if the 'id' attribute starts with 'link'...

```
function test(i) {
    alert("You just clicked on link:" + this.id); 
}
if (document.querySelectorAll('a[id^="link"]')) {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('a[id^="link"]');
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i += 1) {
        elements[i].onclick = test;
    }
} else {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i += 1) {
        if (elements[i].id.substr(0,4) === 'link') {
            elements[i].onclick = test;
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xvwme/3/